# Installing Firebase Storage & GeoFire with Pod - [Minimum development target error]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase and GeoFire in my Podfile. They are working fine. My Podfile.lock file shows versions as:

```
- Firebase (2.5.1)

- GeoFire (1.1.3):
   - Firebase (~> 2.2)
   - FirebaseOSX (~> 2.4)
```

Now I tried to add `pod 'Firebase/Storage'` in my Podfile and `pod install`

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> `Firebase/Storage` required by `Podfile`
>
> Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Storage` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

---

Then, I tried `pod update Firebase`; and now I received another error:

> `Firebase` required by `Podfile`
> `Firebase (~> 2.2)` required by `GeoFire (1.1.3)`
>
> Specs satisfying the `Firebase` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
>
> Specs satisfying the `Firebase (~> 2.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

---

What should I do? How can I install Firebase Storage to my project?

My podfile:

```
 platform :ios, "9.0"
 use_frameworks!

 target 'MyApp' do
   pod 'Firebase'
   pod 'GeoFire', '>= 1.1'
   pod 'Firebase/Storage'
 end
```

---

Edit:

I tried extracting `GeoFire` from podfile, updating `Firebase` and then installing `Firebase/Storage`. It succeed; however when I try re-installing `GeoFire` again, I receive errors:

When I try `pod 'GeoFire', '~> 2.0'` and `pod install`:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> `GeoFire (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`

When I try `pod 'GeoFire'` and `pod install`:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> `Firebase` required by `Podfile`
>
> `Firebase (= 3.2.1)` required by `Podfile.lock`
>
> `Firebase (~> 2.1)` required by `GeoFire (1.1.0)`

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/40

Comment: @Shubhank I got confused how I should solve this issue with this issue. I think the official release is due, as mentioned 4 hours ago in [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/37). Do you think I should wait for the official release?

Comment: yes, wait for a new release. but you can still go ahead and use files locally if you wish to continue development. You can always replace the lib by cocoapod later on.

Comment: is this issue resolve now? cos mine still